# Cross platform way to get caret position in command prompt in python

Tags: python, command-line, caret

I am new to python and am looking for a cross platform way of getting the current caret/text cursor position in the linux terminal or windows command prompt

Can anybody suggest anything?

Comment: Don't really understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @aqua Sorry, typo - corrected it.

Comment: Do you mean in the interactive python prompt, or the prompt in a bash or windows command shell?

Comment: @BryanOakley I mean the prompt in a bash or windows command shell. Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for a way for python to ask some other program where the cursor is. There's no way to do that, cross-platform or otherwise.

Based on your comments to this question, it sounds like you're wanting something a little different, though I could be wrong about that. If you want to create a simple ASCII GUI in a command window you can use the [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) library. With it you can move the cursor around the window, query where the cursor is, etc.

Comment: That is a shame. What I wanted to do was create a small gui for a command line program, and I needed to get the caret position so that I could go back on myself and redraw the gui (I have learnt to set the caret position with colorama and ascii escape sequences).

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: I don't quite understand. Are you wanting to start some other program, then in the middle of edting the line you want to open up a python GUI?

Comment: I was trying to create a Text based ASCII GUI in the command prompt/terminal (for a simple app like a calculator for example)

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: You can use curses to build an ASCII GUI. That's a different question than "how can I get the caret".

Comment: Thank you, I will look into curses - I am still very new to this as you can see :)